# I need a complete guide on image processing and optimization

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, system.drawing, skiasharp, imagesharp

I need a complete guide on image processing and optimization with .Net Core 2..  I tried to use ImageSharp,  CoreCompat.System.Drawing, SkiaSharp, non of these libraries are compatable with .net Core 2

And for sure System.Drawing is not there,, and I cannot find a way to use it,, I think it got removed from core,, I tried everything in this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

But I guess it is not build for .net Core 2, ,And I am stuck    ... Any One Can help me understand what is happening?

Comment: ImageSharp **IS** compatible with NETCORE 2.0 I don't know what you've been looking at.

Answer (score 1):

SkiaSharp will work for .NET Core 2. I have a set of samples:
https://github.com/mattleibow/SkiaSharpDemo

This has a small sample for Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin native and a .NET Core console app.

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Drawing](https://products.aspose.com/drawing/net) and [Aspose.Imaging](https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net) are cross-platform libraries for image drawing and processing supporting .NET Core 2.0+ (I'm one of the developers).